# Looking for a formula to check if a number is the product of a number 2 or greater times a number 3 or greater

Tags: javascript, math, if-statement

I am looking for a formula to use in an IF statement to determine if a given number is the product of a number 2 or greater multiplied by a number 3 or greater.

For instance, 6 is the smallest number that meets the requirement (2 x 3).  7 doesn't, 8 does (2 x 4), 9 does (3 x 3), 10 does (2 x 5), 11 doesn't, 12 does (2 x 6), etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no simple if statement that will identify non-prime numbers > 5 :)

Comment: @Gerrat is there a way to test this without determining its primality?

Comment: Following from your examples, "number" should be "integer" in your requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're doing [primality testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_testing).  You should check out that Wikipedia article - they've got several algorithms to pick from.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Indeed, it seems that all non-prime numbers greater than 5 meet the criteria.  So, using this guys method for identifying prime numbers, I was able to write my IF statement: http://nullman.net/project/JavascriptPrimeNumbers.html

Comment: Nice...didn't think testing primality was required, but apparently is

Answer (score 0):

To check is a number is a multiple of 2, use the mod (%) operator.
so

```
if((x%2 == 0) || (x%3 == 0) )
   //x is a multiple of 2 or 3
```

Comment: Not too sure what exactly is required, sorry english isnt my first language, maybe a bit more elaboration might help me better come up with a good solution?

Comment: it should be `if ( (x % 2 == 0) || (x % 3 == 0) )` otherwise you're right

Comment: That's not what he needs. It would return false for e.g. 35(but has to be true) and true for e.g. 2 or 3(has to be false)

Comment: How would 35 return true? It is not a multiple of 2 or 3 unless I am getting the question wrong :S

Comment: it's not asking if it's a multiple of 2 or 3, it's asking if it has a factor that is at least 2 and another factor that is at least 3.

Answer (score 0):

This finds the smallest factor for n that is at least 2, then finds the smallest factor that is greater than that and greater than 3, and once it does, it returns true.

```
function myFunction(n) {
    if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n) || n%1 || n<6) return false;
    var m = Math.sqrt(n);
    for (var i = 2; i <= m; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            var divided = n / i;
            for (var j = (i > 2) ? i : 3; i <= n / i; i++) {
                if (divided % j == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, you probably don't need the second test. Any composite number over 6 will satisfy this property.

Answer (score 0):

x needs to be a multiple of two factors...(y, z)

```
flag = false; (boolean. set when found);
for(var y = 2; y < x; y++){
   for(var z = 3; z <= (x/y); z++){
       if(y*z == x){
          flag = true;
       }
   }  
}
if(flag){
  now we know that x meets the requirements
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood his question

Comment: it's not asking if it's a multiple of 2 or 3, it's asking if it has a factor that is at least 2 and another factor that is at least 3

Comment: What you wrote is equivalent to `if(x%2==0)`, since `x%2` is either 0 or 1.

Comment: Oh right that was stupid. Would it work now? Doesn't seem like a very efficient way though....

Comment: It should work, but it's very inefficient; it's better to have a single loop `for(var y=2;y<x;y++) if (x%y != 0) { flag = true; break; };` and there are much better algorithms.